# Access iTunes user preferences in OSX Lion

Tags: objective-c, itunes, osx-lion, playlist

I want to access iTunes user preferences such as playlists programmatically.

I use to do it with the following code, however since OSX Lion, I get a nil in response.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *userPreferences = [userDefaults persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.iApps"];

NSArray *databasePaths = [userPreferences objectForKey:@"iTunesRecentDatabasePaths"];
```

I've also made sure my app has all of its entitlements enabled.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story made short: You just can not do it using a Sandboxed app. Turn off Sandboxing and you will see that it works. Why? Well, that's because of containers. A sandbox lives in its own container and so when you call [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] Cocoa uses the path of your container rather than the POSIX path of ~/Library/Preferences which is where com.apple.iApps.plist resides. That sums up why you get nil. Also, there is a blurb on this here in NSUserDefaults: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

How to fix this?

It's really not to bad. First you have to do a little bit of work to get the POSIX path of your home directory. I setup a bunch of NSURL category methods. However the root path is POSIX based. Here is the code snippet to get you started.

1.

```
+ (NSURL *) homePOSIXURL {
struct passwd *pwUser  = getpwuid(getuid());     
const char    *homeDir = pwUser->pw_dir;
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:homeDir] isDirectory:YES]; }
```

When all is said and done, construct a full path to the plist. It hasn't changed for years so you can consider it sticky.

So you might get something that looks like this now:

2.

```
    NSURL * prefURL = [[NSURL libraryPOSIXURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Preferences" isDirectory:YES];
    prefURL = [prefURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"com.apple.iApps.plist"];
```

Now let's turn this plist, which is fairly small into something we can play with. Perhaps NSData? That sounds good, right?

3.

```
 NSData * prefData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:prefURL];
```

Ok, finally we can use this now to get an NSDictionary. Here is how I do it.

4.

```
NSDictionary * prefDict = [NSDictionary collectionFromPropertyList:prefData];
```

Yeah, yeah another Category on NSDictionary. I must have a million of them.

Because I'm in a sharing mood, here ya go:

```
+ (id) collectionFromPropertyList:(NSData *)pList {

    if ( [pList length] > 0 )
        return [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:pList 
                                                         options:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                          format:nil error:nil];
    return nil;
}
```

So, you think we are done? Well, almost. If you get this far, you will get a deny like so:

> deny file-read-data
>   /Users/UserName/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iApps.plist

Are we loving our Sandboxed app?! Basically add your temporary entitlement and you should be off to the races again. Best of luck to ya!

Comment: Another easier way to get the contents of the plist into a dict would be like this:

NSDictionary* plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:prefURL];

Comment: Hey, what about NSHomeDirectory(); or NSHomeDirectoryForUser(NSString *userName); for getting the home directory?

Comment: Nope...those will return a folder in your container if the app is sandboxed.

Comment: i still get deny after adding the temporary exception. The message looks like this sandboxd[5698] ([5696]): <AppName>(5696) deny file-read-data /Users/<CurrentUser>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPhoto.plist. How does the temporary exception look like? I added something like this in the entitlements plist  <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.home-relative-path.read-write</key>
 <true/>
 <key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write</key>
 <true/>

Comment: You only need ...home-relative-path.read-only. It's value should be an array. Then add this as an object in that array: /Library/Preferences/